# C wrong sum result with doubles

Tags: c, printf

I there.

I'm learning C and I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double buyval, deliveredval, change;

    printf("What's the buy value? ");
    scanf("%lf", &buyval);

    do{
        printf("What's the value delivered? ");
        scanf("%lf", &deliveredval);

        if (deliveredval < buyval){
            printf("Delivered value must be greater then buy value \n\n");
        }
    } while (deliveredval < buyval);

    change = deliveredval - buyval;

    printf("Change is %4.2lf", change);
    return 0;
}
```

With this code, the last print is always 0.00 but is I change

```
printf("Change is %4.2lf", change);
```

to

```
printf("Change is %4.2f", change);
```

It works as expected. Why is that? Doubles aren't formatted as lf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"%f"` is for `double`s (and `float`s which are converted to `double` automagically); `%Lf` is for `long double`s.
You can read all about [`printf`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1) specifiers in the [C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html) (or in [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)).

The `l` in the format specifier `"%lf"` has no effect: `"%lf"` (the same as `"%f"`) is to print `double`s.

Your result should be the same with any sane C99 compiler / implementation.

According to my documents, in C89, `"%lf"` is an invalid format specifier; and if you are using a C89 compiler / implementation, it's Undefined Behaviour the use it.

---

Note that the rules for `scanf` are a bit different.

Answer (score 3):

In variable argument lists, `float` values are automatically converted to `double`; `char` and `short`  to `int`.  Therefore, `printf` needs only `%f` for `double` values (to which float values are converted to).

Pointers are not converted - this would not make much sense. This is the reason, why `scanf` needs to distinguish between `%f` for `float` targets and `%lf` for `double` targets.

Comment: +1 for referring the fact that `scanf` takes **pointers** and these are not subject to default argument promotions.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `%f` to print doubles. `%lf` is only for long doubles.

Comment: Thanks. And on the scanf I should use %f instead of %lf?

Comment: `%Lf` is used for `long double`. `%lf` should be the same as `%f` in printf according to the C99 standard.

Comment: No. in `scanf`, `%f` is only for `float`, and `%lf` is for double. (use `%llf` to scan long double)

Comment: It is `%Lf` not `%lf` the character 'l' is for long integer types, like `%ld`